# Why 0% in Jacoco coverage for integration tests

Tags: spring-boot, maven-3, code-coverage, jacoco-maven-plugin, maven-failsafe-plugin

I have setup maven project to get the integration test coverage in my it profile. But the jacoco report shows 0% for all the classes.

My main POM Jacoco integration setup section in the profile and failsafe plugin:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-failsafe-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <!--
                        Invokes both the integration-test and the verify goals of the
                        Failsafe Maven plugin
                    -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-tests</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!--
                                Skips integration tests if the value of skip.it.tests
                                property is true
                            -->
                            <argLine>@{failsafeArgLine}</argLine>
                            <skipTests>${skip.it.tests}</skipTests>

                            <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>none</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                            <includes>
                                <!-- Include your Cucumber tests, as an example -->
                                <include>**/*CucumberTests.java</include>
                                <include>**/*IT.java</include>
                            </includes>

                            <systemPropertyVariables>
                                <it.server.port>${random.http.port}</it.server.port>
                                <it.jmx.port>${random.jmx.port}</it.jmx.port>
                            </systemPropertyVariables>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
       </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

.....
<profiles>
     <profile>
            <id>it</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <packaging.type>jar</packaging.type>
                <run.profiles>it</run.profiles>
                <skip.it.tests>true</skip.it.tests>
                <skipTests>true</skipTests>
            </properties>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <append>true</append>
                            <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. ;-->
                            <destFile>${user.dir}/target/jacoco-it.exec</destFile>
                            <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data.-->
                            <dataFile>${user.dir}/target/jacoco-it.exec</dataFile>
                            <!--  Sets the name of the property containing the settings for JaCoCo runtime agent.-->
                            <propertyName>failsafeArgLine</propertyName>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>**/*App*</exclude>
                                <exclude>**/test/**/*</exclude>
                                <exclude>**/it/**/*</exclude>
                                <exclude>**/config/*Config*</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                            <!--  Sets the output directory for the code coverage report.-->
                            <outputDirectory>${user.dir}/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-it</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                            <!--
                                Ensures that the code coverage report for integration tests after
                                integration tests have been run.
                            -->
                            <execution>
                                <id>post-integration-test</id>
                                <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>report</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
```

The profile setting of the module POM which has api tests where the command is executed

```
<profile>
    <id>it</id>
    <properties>
        <skip.it.tests>false</skip.it.tests>
        <spring.profile>it</spring.profile>
        <skipTests>true</skipTests>  -- This is for unit tests
    </properties>
</profile>
```

However I can see `jacoco-it.exec` file has been generated and the report file as below.

[image]

Version:

```
<jacoco.plugin.version>0.8.3</jacoco.plugin.version>
<maven-failsafe-plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</maven-failsafe-plugin.version>
```

Command to execute tests:  `mvn clean verify -P it`. This will spin up a server and run all integration tests (api end point tests) there.

Further when setup for unit tests that work as expected with `surefire plugin` with showing proper coverage in jacoco reports.

Comment: Are you using `PowerMock` for `Integration Tests`?

Comment: @Fatih Not for integration tests, but for unit tests. integration tests on serenity and rest-assured

Comment: did you manage to find the answer?